# Best way to use conditional for useContext in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-context

I have a `CommonChild` component that called in two components: `Parent1` and `Parent2`.

Bold `Parent1` and `Parent2` are use different `AppContext`.

Please look some simple code below:

```js
import React, { useState, useContext, createContext } from 'react'

//Create two createContext of Parents
const ContextParent1 = createContext();
const ContextParent2 = createContext();

//Create two providers of Parents
const AppProviderParent1 = (props) => {
    const [state] = useState("This is AppProviderParent1")
    return (
        <ContextParent1.Provider value={state}>
            {props.children}
        </ContextParent1.Provider>
    )
}
const AppProviderParent2 = (props) => {
    const [state] = useState("This is AppProviderParent2")
    return (
        <ContextParent2.Provider value={state}>
            {props.children}
        </ContextParent2.Provider>
    )
}

//Two parents called CommonChild, but different AppProvider (created above)
const Parent1 = (props) => {
    return (
        <AppProviderParent1 {...props}>
            <CommonChild />
        </AppProviderParent1>
    )
}
const Parent2 = (props) => {
    return (
        <AppProviderParent2 {...props}>
            <CommonChild />
        </AppProviderParent2>
    )
}

//CommonChild that try to use useContext to get value
const CommonChild = () => {
    const context = useContext(...) //how to use useContext?
    return (
        <p>This is CommonChild Component</p>
    )
}
```

I don't know how to use `useContext` in `CommonChild` which sensibly.

Thank you for your help

Comment: You create a single context `const MyContext = createContext(<Default value here>);` and then create Providers for the context in each of your parents changing the `value` property that you provide. You then use the context in the child by calling `const context = useContext(MyContext)` and it will receive the most relevant parent context or the default value if no parent context is found.

Comment: Oh. You mean, both `AppProviderParent1` and `AppProviderParent2` can use same `createContext`?

Comment: Yeah, if there is no difference between the properties they hold. i.e. Parent 1 could provide values `{ propA: true}` and parent 2 could provider values `{ propA: false}`

Comment: I'll try it. Thank you

Comment: Here is an example [https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-jheevm?file=index.tsx](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-jheevm?file=index.tsx). Note: uses typescript

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1**

You can pass down an **identifier** to `CommonChild` that tells who is calling it. Then use the conditional operation `?` like so-

```
const Parent1 = (props) => {
    return (
        <AppProviderParent1 {...props}>
             
            {/********** Pass down the caller string **********/}
            <CommonChild caller='parent1' />
        </AppProviderParent1>
    )
}
const Parent2 = (props) => {
    return (
        <AppProviderParent2 {...props}>
            
        {/********** Pass down the caller string **********/}
            <CommonChild caller='parent2' />
        </AppProviderParent2>
    )
}

//CommonChild that try to use useContext to get value
const CommonChild = ({caller}) => {
    const context = 
        useContext(caller === 'parent1' ?  AppProviderParent1 : AppProviderParent2);
    return (
        <p>This is CommonChild Component</p>
    )
}
```

**Method 2**

As you stated in the comment, you have multiple contexts and children as well. For this, you can put all the contexts in an array, and pass a number to the child component indicating the ***index*** of the context to use.

```
const appProviders = [AppProviderParent1, AppProviderParent2];

const Parent1 = (props) => {
    return (
        <AppProviderParent1 {...props}>
             
            {/********** Pass down index of AppProvider **********/}
            <CommonChild providerIndex={0} />
        </AppProviderParent1>
    )
}
const Parent2 = (props) => {
    return (
        <AppProviderParent2 {...props}>
            
        {/********** Pass down index of AppProvider **********/}
            <CommonChild providerIndex={1} />
        </AppProviderParent2>
    )
}


const CommonChild = ({providerIndex}) => {

    const context = 
        useContext(appProviders[providerIndex];
    return (
        <p>This is CommonChild Component</p>
    )
}
```

This way, you can pass the relevant Context to any child you want.

Comment: I don't like this away because I have many child use in both Parent components